# How to generate protobuf files from proto messages?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I already have a `FileDescriptorProto` object which is a proto message and I want to convert the object to string representation just like the contents in a proto file. The language I use is Go.

Comment: Do you have a protobuf-encoded message, or do you have a decoded Go struct value?

Comment: I have a decoded go struct value and the type is `proto.FileDescriptorProto`.

Comment: To restate: you have the **compiled** proto schema (the `FileDescriptorProto`), and you want to decompile it back to a text .proto schema - is that right? AFAIK, there are no *direct* tools to do this, but it should be entirely possible - although perhaps slightly ambiguous (meaning, it might not give back exactly the same text input, but it should be semantically useful enough). The work to do this would be similar to the work for writing a language plugin for protoc

Comment: Why would one want to do this? What is the end goal?

Comment: @colminator I want to write a protobuf plugin to modify proto files  then pass the modified files to other plugins.